# Imagesc function on Matlab: problems in converting 3D shapes in 2D

Tags: matlab, 3d

I'm currently using imagesc function in Matlab for converting 3d shapes in 2d ones . Usually it works fine, but I tried to create a 3D ramp and then to rotate it but on imagesc I cannot visualize the rotation (in 3d it works).

The code is this:

```
    N=100;
    x = linspace(0,10000,N);
    y = linspace(0,10000,N);
    screen_size = get(0, 'ScreenSize');
    screen_dim=[screen_size(1,3) screen_size(1,4)];
    center=.5;

    [xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
    zz=xx+screen_size(1,3)/2; %centrato sula metá della lunghezza dello schermo
    surf(xx,yy,zz)
    hold on
    [az el R] = cart2sph(xx,yy,zz);
    az=az+pi/3;

    [xx1 yy1 zz1] = sph2cart(az,el,R);
    surf(xx1,yy1,zz1)
    hold off

    figure(); imagesc(zz)%ramp
    figure(); imagesc(zz1)%rotated ramp
```

Can u please tell me what' s wrong with this code?

Thx a lot.

Comment: Youll need to create a zz1 *alligned* to x-y axis, else `imgesc` will take the zz1 (that is square and has no information about what x,y values each z belongs to) and just plot it as it is. You will need to create a zz1 with NaNs where `zz1(n,m)` corresponds to `x=n` and `y=m`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but here it goes.

The 3D rotation that you apply modifies the *x* and *y* values (in addition to the *z* values), but you lose that information when you call `imagesc` using just the transformed *z* values.

See if this is what you want:

```
surf(xx1, yy1, zz1, 'edgecolor', 'none') %// tracciare la superficie senza bordi
view(2)                                  %// guardare da su
axis equal                               %// stessa scala in entrambi assi
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer but I need specifically the imagesc function..do u think is it possible to not lose x and y information with imagesc?

Comment: @Maky Maybe use `interp2` to convert the transformed _x_, _y_ into a rectangular grid parallel to the axes (with extra values). I think that's what Ander proposed in his comment

Comment: I like how you used italian for the comments!

Comment: @Ander Yes... I don't have many opportunities for practicing it! :-D